# Does C have a garbage collector like Java does?

Tags: c, list, malloc

What happens in C if we do something like this in Java:

```
    temp.next = temp.next.next;
```

What will happen to temp.next node?  In Java there is a dump/ garbage collector; is there something similar in C?

Comment: The title of the question should be "Does C have a garbage collector" The question should be different. The answer is no.

Comment: C does not have garbage collection. If you're interested in knowing why, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039274/was-there-a-specific-reason-garbage-collection-was-not-designed-for-c/4039474#4039474

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing will happen to it. It will continue to use memory and you will have lost any means to use it or free it.

In C you have to explicitly `free` stuff you obtained via `malloc` when you're done with it, there's no such thing as reference counting or garbage collection.

Answer (score 6):

C does not have automatic garbage collection.  If you lose track of an object, you have what is known as a 'memory leak'.  The memory will still be allocated to the program as a whole, but nothing will be able to use it if you've lost the last pointer to it.  Memory resource management is a key requirement on C programs.  So, whenever you dynamically allocate memory in C, you need to know when and how it will be released.

There are tools dedicated to helping you.  One notable one is [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/), which uses similar technology to the commercially available [Purify](http://www.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/).

Answer (score 1):

In c if you don't `free` the memory you allocated via `malloc` it will just sit there doing nothing until the program execution ends.

Unlike Java, C has no garbage collection.