# Installing the Boehm GC on OS X

Tags: c, garbage-collection, clang, ld, boehm-gc

I want to install the [Boehm garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector) garbage collector on MacOS. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678440/installing-libgc-on-osx-boehms-garbage-collector) guide but it did not help; invoking `brew install libgc` did nothing. Here is my example code that I am trying to run:

```c
#include <gc/gc.h>

int main() {
    void* eight_bytes = GC_MALLOC(8);
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GC_malloc", referenced from:
      _main in boehm_invocation-369838.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone know of a good way to install this GC without building it from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I installed libgc on mac, as you did, the files were installed to `/usr/local/Cellar/bdw-gc/`. Then, when it came time to compile my code I had to run:

```sh
$ LIBGC=/usr/local/Cellar/bdw-gc/VERSION/
$ gcc ... -I$LIBGC/include/ ... $LIBGC/lib/libgc.a other.a ...
```

When you install libgc, its not included in your system path. You need to explicitly add it.

Also in my code I used:

```c
#include "gc.h"
```

And not `<gc/gc.h>`.